# Finding the thread that has an object locked with Memory Analysis Tool (MAT)

Tags: java, deadlock

I am in the process of diagnosing a Java deadlock situation by looking through an .hprof file with MAT. I can see clearly that two threads are blocked waiting to synchronise on a hashmap. What I cannot find is which thread *does* have the hashmap locked.

Can anyone shine a little light upon the darkness of my ignorance?

M.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the thread stack analysis on your heap dump which will give an overview of the objects allocated in each of the threads.

To access this information, in your memory analyser tool, click on Java Basic -> Thread Overview.

Steps to debug the dump file is mentioned in the below link.

refer the below link:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Ftasks%2Fanalyzingthreads.html

Comment: Page moved to:
https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Ftasks%2Fanalyzingthreads.html